# Moment Js How can I tell when I'm within an hour of target time?

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to try and figure out if a user is within an hour of their intended departure time. If they are, a button in the UI is enabled allowing them to begin their departure.
So, for example, if they're meant to leave at 3:00pm then they shouldn't be allowed to hit the button before 1:59 pm, but at 2:00 they should.

Currently I'm using the following for my function:

```
const calculateTime = (depTime: string) => {
  const currentTime = moment();
  const hourBeforeDepartue = moment(depTime).subtract(1, 'hour');
  const isWithinHour = currentTime.isBetween(hourBeforeDepartue, depTime);
  return isWithinHour;
};
```

The issue here is that my function is returning false when I test it with jest:

```
import { calculateTime } from './calculateTime';
import moment from 'moment';

    describe('Function that determines if the time is within departure range', () => {
          it('Is in the hour of departure', () => {
            const oneHourFromNow = moment()
              .add(1, 'hour')
              .format('H:H');
            console.log(oneHourFromNow);
            const response = calculateTime(oneHourFromNow);
            expect(response).toBe(true);
          });
        });
```

I'm not sure why it's returning false and I don't know of a better method to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up grabbing a plug-in for moment.js called twix. This plug-in checks whether the current time is between the targeted departure time and the time an hour prior to it.

```
import moment from 'moment';
require('twix');

export class Time {
  time: string;
  constructor(time: string) {
    this.time = time;
  }
}

export type DepartureTime = string;

export class CheckTime extends Time {
  public constructor(departureTime: DepartureTime) {
    super(departureTime);
    this.isWithinHour = this.isWithinHour.bind(this);
  }
  private validateTime(departureTime: DepartureTime): boolean {
    return moment(departureTime).isValid();
  }

  public isWithinHour(time: DepartureTime): boolean | null {
    if (!this.validateTime(time)) {
      return null;
    }
    const departureTime = moment(time).format();
    const oneHourPrior = moment(time)
      .subtract(1, 'h')
      .format();
    const timing = moment(oneHourPrior).twix(departureTime);
    return timing.isCurrent();
  }
}
```